# Number of permutation of a particular string is divisible by a number

Tags: algorithm, math

Suppose I have a **multiset** of 10 digits, for example `S = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 8, 9 }`. Is there any method other than brute force to find the number of distinct permutations of the elements of `S` such that when a permutation is regarded as a ten digit integer, it is divisible by a particular number `n` ? `n` will be in the range `1` to `10000`.

For example:

if `S = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 }` and `n = 10`, the result is `0` (since no permutation of those 10 digits will ever give a number divisible by 10)

if `S = { 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 2}` and `n = 2`, the result is `9! / 2^4` (since we must have the `2` at the end, there are `9!` ways to permute the other elements, but there are four pairs of identical elements)

Comment: Seems hard to me.  Is this homework?

Comment: No, it's not homework, since i am not student now, it's only for learning something new.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you asking for an algorithm that answers "What strings over my alphabet have a unique permutation count divisible by a given bounded NUM?"  Or is it "What permutations of the given string are, when taking as an integer, divisible by a given bounded NUM?"

Comment: Sounds very much like a project Euler problem (www.projecteuler.net), but I couldn't find it there! :-)  I cannot see how this is done without using bruteforce.  OFTEN (but not always), finding the "exact" number suggests brute-force.

Comment: not it's not alphabet, it's only digit 0-9.  What permutations of the given string are, when taking as an integer,is divisible by a given number which can be any number  between 1-10000.

Comment: Ok.  One more question: are you asking for the *count* of these divisible permutations, or for the *list* of permutations itself?

Comment: no, only counting the number of divisible permutation suffice, no need to know the corresponding permutation.

Comment: For example; S = {121213122} and Num=11  found the number of divisible perms. are 121(first 3 digit), 121(digits 2-4) and 22(last 2 digit) and the result is "3". Do I understand true?

Comment: I am providing an example , suppose, S={123434} and NUM=2, and the answer is 90,->  by placing one 4 at the right side you  5!/2!=60 permutation divisible by NUM and  by placing 2 at the right side you get 5!/(2!2!)=30, so total 90 permutation, but the real problem arise when NUM is not single digit number. Any more idea.

Comment: Is there a great reason you can't use brute force? 10! isn't exactly big.

Comment: @yes, the reason is everyone knows brute force, and i need to know more. And a faster solution certainly exist(may be bruteforce but with a good pruning strategy). And i want to know that.

Answer (score 2):

You could prune the search like so: find the prime factorization of NUM. Obviously to be divisible by NUM, a permutation needs to be divisible by all of NUM's prime factors. Hence you can use **[simple divisibility rules](http://www.mathsisfun.com/divisibility-rules.html)** to avoid generating many invalid candidates.

Comment: How do it speed up?? it also  need's to generate all the permutation or checking all the multiple of prime factor???

Comment: Well, for example if 2 is a prime factor of NUM (which was renamed to n apparently), then you know that any valid candidate must have the last digit even. This means that you can avoid generating and testing any permutation where the last digit is odd; you already know they won't be divisible by n.

Comment: As another more extreme example, if 3 is a prime factor, then you can check whether the sum of numbers in `S` is divisible by 3. If it is not, then you don't need to generate any candidates at all: you already know there is no solution. On the other hand, if the sum is a multiple of 3, then you can be sure that any permutation will satisfy that criterion, and you can move on to the other prime factors.

Answer (score 1):

I have some thoughts but it's not organized into an actual algorithm.

For N=2, we simply see how many even digits we can put on the end of our permutations and calculate the number that way.

For N=3, we know the sum of the digits has to be divisible by 3. This means we can freely put any 3s, 6s, 9s and 0s in our permutations, but any other digits we'll have to put in pairs that sum to 3, 6 or 9 (or a triplet of 1s). I don't think this would be too hard to implement.

For N=4, we can do something similar to N=2.

I think we can come up with cases like this for up to N=10 (N=7 might be tricky). Then, we might be able to do any N > 10 by factoring it. For example, if N=18, any and all permutations that are divisible by N are also divisible by 2 and 9. Of course if N is a prime number we might be in trouble.

Comment: So it's pretty much like my answer then? :)

Comment: Yes :) I didn't read your answer too closely before I posted my own, then I looked up and saw you had said basically the same thing but more succinctly. Then I closed the tab out of embarrassment.

Answer (score 0):

My idea: sort the digits of S increasing and decreasing. Now you have the min and max that can be generated from S. Now take all multiples of N in the interval min, max and see which of them are formed by the digits in S.

Comment: this is even worse than normal bruteforce, if NUM is 2, then number of multiple of between- 1000000000-9999999999, can you imagine!!!! not finished yet, now check for count number of corresponding digit in S, another for loop inside every multiple!!!!

Comment: You are right but I still maintain that for large values of N you are inspecting way less numbers than with brute force.

Comment: for large value its may be better, but for my problem, NUM is 2-10000,so it need an way that can coup with any number in these range.